# AnyObject vs Any with struct types

Tags: swift, struct

I'm having a tad bit of trouble differentiating between AnyObject and Any. In Apple's Documentation it says that "AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type", yet when I declare an array that holds AnyObject, I'm able to put struct types in there, which are not classes. So,

```
var array : [AnyObject] = [6, "Foo", "Bar"]
```

works, which doesn't really make sense since an Int is a struct type. I'm trying to interact with an API, and trying to decide if the hashes sent down from the backend would be best served as [String : AnyObject] or [String : Any]. I'm trying to go with the former since it's more specific. Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: `var array : [AnyObject] = [6, "Foo", "Bar"]` does not compile in Swift 3 – are you using Swift 2?

Comment: You need to do this for Swift 3  `var array : [AnyObject] = [6 as AnyObject, "Foo" as AnyObject, "Bar" as AnyObject]`

Comment: for Swift 3 you can also just do `var array : [Any] = [6, "Foo", "Bar"]`

Comment: [I believe that this comment by Joe Groff on a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420?focusedCommentId=17394&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17394) "is/as AnyObject always succeed for all types now. It's behaving as intended" is relevant, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: so when you cast 6 as AnyObject, what does it convert it to if it goes from a struct to a class type?

Comment: @Coach `Int` will get bridged to `NSNumber` (specifically a `_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber` in Swift 3, but that's just a implementation detail). You can test this out for yourself by doing `print(type(of: 2 as AnyObject))`. Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/content//documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61

Comment: @Hamish so would that mean, if nil came down from the backend and was cast to AnyObject, it would be bridged to NSNull?

Comment: @Coach No, currently Swift `Optional`s don't get bridged to anything meaningful in Objective-C (they get boxed in a special `_SwiftValue`) – although in Swift 3.0.1 it will be the case that they get bridged to `NSNull`, or their payload – see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in the [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl) and here are the results.

Swift 2.2:

```
Swift Ver. 2.2 (Jan 11, 2016)
Platform: Linux (x86_64)

ERROR at line 1, col 28: value of type 'Int' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'
var array : [AnyObject] = [6, "Foo", "Bar"]
                           ^
swift-build: error: exit(1): ["/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", "/swift-execution/.build/debug/TempCode.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

Swift 3.0:

```
Swift Ver. 3.0 (Release)
Platform: Linux (x86_64)

ERROR at line 1, col 28: value of type 'Int' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'
var array : [AnyObject] = [6, "Foo", "Bar"]
                           ^
                             as! AnyObject
```

So it doesn't compile in either. However it's important to understand that:

> ...number literals do not have an explicit type in and of themselves. Their type is inferred only at the point that they are evaluated by the compiler.

(Quoted from [The Swift 3 Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html))

For example `6` will be evaluated as `Int` by default, but can also be evaluated implicitly as `Double` or `Float` or `UInt` etc. based on context. For example:

```
var i : Float = 6 // Perfectly fine - implicitly evaluated as Float
```

But these numeric literals cannot be implicitly evaluated as `AnyObject`.

Comment: yeah but if you do `let array : [AnyObject] = [6 as AnyObject, "foo" as AnyObject, "bar" as AnyObject]` it compiles perfectly fine, yet you are converting the 6, which is a struct, to a class instance....how is that succeeding?

Comment: It is bridging it to NSNumber, try this in a playground:
import Foundation \n
var i : AnyObject = 6 as AnyObject \n
print (type(of: i)) \n - So the reason it works is a Foundation thing, not a Swift thing, I don't really understand it beyond that myself :)